# Mp4 file created from ffmpeg can play on Simulator/PC browser but can't play on iOS app/safari in real device

Tags: ios, ffmpeg, safari, mp4, h.264

The backend team uses ffmpeg to create video from images.
The strange thing is that the video can be played on Mac browser/iPhone Simulator but not on browser/iOS app on real phone.

I tried using AVPlayer to print the error but error = nil

here is the file: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/chatchatapp123.appspot.com/o/image_rendered.mp4?alt=media

here is its metadata: https://www.metadata2go.com/result/46e72635-7fac-46ee-acfe-cb6ffda49692

Has anyone encountered this before and if so, any ideas as to why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've noticed, `field order` in metadata is `tt`, which means
Interlaced video, top field coded and displayed first

But according to the document of “HTTP Live Streaming” from Apple, there is a description,” Important: Interlaced video is not supported on iOS devices.”, which is written on the official document.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/http_live_streaming/hls_authoring_specification_for_apple_devices